# Navigating to another stack group in NavigationContainer

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

In my App.tsx I'm using createNativeStackNavigator and I'm trying to dismiss the modal that is "Project_Creation" and navigate to Main

```
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Group>
          <Stack.Screen name="Main" component={DrawerNavigator} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
          <Stack.Screen name="Details" component={ChannelDetails} />
          <Stack.Screen name="Profile" component={Profile} />
        </Stack.Group>
        <Stack.Group screenOptions={{ stackPresentation: 'modal', headerShown: false }}>
          <Stack.Screen
            options={{ headerTitle: 'Create Project' }}
            name="Project_Creation"
            component={ProjectCreationNavigator}
          />
        </Stack.Group>
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
```

I'm not sure if it's because createNativeStackNavigator is not as customizable as createStackNavigator or if I can't navigate to another Stack Group from one of the screens in ProjectCreationNavigator but it keeps getting errors.

With navigation.dismiss() I get

```
navigation.dismiss() is not a function
```

with navigation.reset({index: 0, name: "Main"}) I get

```
undefined is not an object
```

I'd love to figure out how to navigate to "Main".

Answer (score 1):

Update::

I realized the problem. In separate navigator component I had NavigationContainer wrapped. When I removed that it worked

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: yes please could you please elaborate a it more thanks!